# Fast computation moving window correlations

Tags: python, performance, vectorization, correlation

I have a set of n vectors, length l, and what to compute the correlation of neighbouring vector pairs [(1,2), (2,3), ...] in a window that moves through the entries of the given vectors, up to a maximum lag time. I have some code that works but is quite slow for the long vectors that I have, as it loops quite a bit.

I now have tried to create an array, that contained all the shifted windows of the second vector using `as_strided` but now I need to find a way to compute efficiently the correlation between one window of my first vector with this array and then move this window.

What I tried is the following:

```
A=pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
B=pd.DataFrame({"B":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4]})

as_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided

win = 3
MAX_LAG = len(B) - (win - 1)

v= as_strided(B.B, (MAX_LAG, win), (B.B.values.strides * 2), writeable=False)
vd=pd.DataFrame(v)

correlations= A.A.rolling(win).corr(vd)
print(correlations)

           0    1          2
0        NaN  NaN        NaN
1        NaN  NaN        NaN
2  1.000e+00  1.0  1.000e+00
3  1.000e+00  1.0  1.000e+00
4  1.000e+00  1.0  1.000e+00
5  1.000e+00  1.0  1.000e+00
6  1.000e+00  1.0  9.230e-15
7  1.000e+00  0.0 -1.000e+00
8  1.846e-14 -1.0 -1.000e+00
```

This is already in the right track, but then again not what I want. I want ultimately an output something like this:

```
    0    1    2 ... 8
0  1.0  NaN  NaN ... NaN
1  1.0  1.0 NaN ... NaN
2  1.0  1.0  1.0 ...NaN
3  1.0  1.0  1.0 ...NaN
4  1.0  1.0  1.0 ...NaN
5  1.0  1.0  1.0 ...NaN
6  0.0  0.0  0.0 ...NaN
7  -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 ...NaN
8  -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 ... -1
```

The NaN should come from the fact, that I do not want to correlate windows in vector A with windows in Vector B, that have a lower index.

Any idea how I could do that efficiently?

Thank you so much!